# Orderby Clause Error in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm getting an error when I'm executing the below query:

```
INSERT Into dbo.[DRC_76_A-05 Deposits SBP Coding] 
SELECT '20180228' as BusinessDate,z.* 
FROM ( SELECT IND.L_SBP_CODE, TDEPO.Type_of_Deposit, 
              ISNULL(SUM(AC.WORKING_BALANCE),0) AS AMOUNT 
       FROM InsightSource.BS.ACCOUNT AC 
       LEFT JOIN InsightSource.BS.CUSTOMER CUS ON AC.CUSTOMER = CUS.[@ID] 
       INNER JOIN KMBL.DBO.TYPE_OF_DEPOSITS TDEPO ON AC.CATEGORY = TDEPO.Cat_ID 
       LEFT JOIN InsightSource.BS.INDUSTRY_LocalRef IND ON CUS.INDUSTRY = IND.[@Id] 
       GROUP BY IND.L_SBP_CODE, TDEPO.Type_of_Deposit 
       ORDER BY TDEPO.Type_of_Deposit ASC ) Z
```

**Error:**

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified

Comment: Add `top N` to the view definition

Comment: show the rest of you code  ...

Comment: instead of screenshot,  post the sql here.

Comment: @scaisEdge INSERT Into dbo.[DRC_76_A-05 Deposits SBP Coding] 
 Select '20180228' as BusinessDate,z.* 
 From 
 (
  SELECT
  IND.L_SBP_CODE, 
  TDEPO.Type_of_Deposit, 
  ISNULL(SUM(AC.WORKING_BALANCE),0) AS AMOUNT
  FROM InsightSource.BS.ACCOUNT AC LEFT JOIN InsightSource.BS.CUSTOMER CUS ON AC.CUSTOMER = CUS.[@ID]
  INNER JOIN KMBL.DBO.TYPE_OF_DEPOSITS TDEPO ON AC.CATEGORY = TDEPO.Cat_ID
  LEFT JOIN InsightSource.BS.INDUSTRY_LocalRef IND ON CUS.INDUSTRY = IND.[@Id]

  GROUP BY
  IND.L_SBP_CODE, TDEPO.Type_of_Deposit

  ORDER BY 
  TDEPO.Type_of_Deposit ASC
)Z

Comment: uodate your question and add your code  .. in question not in comment

Answer (score 1):

You should move the ORDER BY outside the subquery

```
  INSERT Into dbo.[DRC_76_A-05 Deposits SBP Coding] 
  Select '20180228' as BusinessDate,z.* 
  From ( 
      SELECT IND.L_SBP_CODE
            , TDEPO.Type_of_Deposit
            , ISNULL(SUM(AC.WORKING_BALANCE),0) AS AMOUNT 
      FROM InsightSource.BS.ACCOUNT AC 
      LEFT JOIN InsightSource.BS.CUSTOMER CUS ON AC.CUSTOMER = CUS.[@ID] 
      INNER JOIN KMBL.DBO.TYPE_OF_DEPOSITS TDEPO ON AC.CATEGORY = TDEPO.Cat_ID 
      LEFT JOIN InsightSource.BS.INDUSTRY_LocalRef IND ON CUS.INDUSTRY = IND.[@Id] 
      GROUP BY IND.L_SBP_CODE, TDEPO.Type_of_Deposit 
 ) Z
  ORDER BY Z.Type_of_Deposit ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self explanatory :

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, **subqueries**, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified

You are doing an ORDER BY in a **subquery**. It is useless in all cases, so you can simply get rid of it.

Do your ORDER BY in your main query, when all your data is gathered and filtered

Comment: if i comment that line in subquery it compile successfully but in my ssrs report results are coming not in a order by form.

Comment: read my answer again: you have to move your ORDER BY in your main query.

Comment: @MAunAli You could insert an order by in the main query